# How to click on specific button on a page using selenium, when only button name is present in html?

Tags: selenium

On a webpage 3 buttons are present and all 3 buttons have same name eg:, 'continue'. In its html no id is present. I need to click on second button.
Also without using xpath locator.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please post a link to the page or the relevant HTML along with the code you have tried and any error messages or why the code isn't accomplishing what you expect.

Comment: why not use `xpath`? Are `css selectors` also off the table? This is exactly what those are good at. You would have to provide some `html` for any real help with those though.

Comment: Can you provide the following information: 1. What is your objective? 2. What are you trying to do? 3. What have you tried? Show code. 4. What works for you? 5. Where are you stuck?  On providing these answers you will surely get some innovative ideas from our experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elements = this.browser.FindElements(By.Name("//*[contains(@name,'continue')]"));
element[0].Click()
```

The above code clicks the first element of the 3 elements that are returned.

We can also click the element if you have a unique sibling or preceding element.It could help a lot if you provide the original html code.